# Why can't I erase a part in my layer?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I'm hoping that this is the right place to ask, but I've just started out with Adobe Illustrator CS6 and I'm having some 'beginner' issues.

If you look at the following:
[image]
See, I can only erase the parts that seem blue here, but the black parts can't even be erased? It seems like there is some partial layering going on here, but I can't really figure out what? I would just like to make one sketch and have a single layer for that sketch. This is how the layers are:

[image]

Would someone happen to know how to solve this?

*EDIT*
[image]
*EDIT2*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're in isolation mode (as seen in your layers panel), which isolates whatever you have selected and means you can't edit anything outside of that selection. You either need to get out of isolation mode completely or exit isolation mode and select everything you want to edit *before* entering isolation mode.

You can hit <kbd>esc</kbd> to get out of isolation mode, or choose "Exit Isolation Mode" from the dropdown menu on the Layers panel.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've gotten out of the isolation mode (as you can see in the picture I've added in my original post), but I can still not erase the parts that don't get blue when I select the sketch.

Comment: Only the top group in your layers panel is selected, does it work if you select it all? (either hit cmd+a or click the circle next to "Layer 1" in the layers panel)

Comment: Make sure you don't have any locked layers/object too (they'll have a little padlock next the eye in the layers panel)

Comment: I've selected it all, but still some fractions stay unselected (see edited post). I've also displayed the layers (which seem ridiculously many?) and none are locked, as far as I can see. I'm surprised that every single line is a single layer.

Comment: If you scroll down the layers panel is there anything not selected (doesn't have a blue square next to it)? Not sure what could be going on otherwise.

Comment: And no lots of layers is normal :)

Comment: I've 'solved' it by selecting the sketch without selecting the irresponsive part with this lasso-option.

Comment: not sure why the lasso tool would be any different but glad you got it working :)